# How can I make the overlay not apply to the header or top part?

Tags: html, css, tailwind-css, overlay, tailwind-ui

the overlay applies the whole page except side menu
here is my header code

```
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Snapp</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../Assets/css/output.css">
    <script src="//unpkg.com/alpinejs" defer></script>
</head>

<body dir="rtl">
    <div x-data="dropdown" class="bg-white ">
        <header
            class="relative z-40 flex flex-row-reverse items-center justify-between h-16 px-5 xl:px-20 xl:h-24 xl:flex-row gap-x-6 xl:container xl:justify-start">
            <img src="../Assets/imgs/snappTextLogo.svg" alt="snappTextLogo">

            <div @click="toggle" class="xl:hidden">
                <img x-show="!open" class="inline-block size-8" src="../Assets/imgs/menuIcon.svg" alt="menuIcon-bars">
                <img x-show="open" class="inline-block size-8" src="../Assets/imgs/closeIcon.svg" alt="closeIcon">
            </div>


            <ul x-show="open"
                class="max-w-[500px] w-full h-screen xl:hidden flex flex-col bg-white text-slate-500 *:p-4 absolute top-[64px] right-0 border-t">
                <li>item1</li>
                <li>item2</li>
                <li>item4</li>
                <li>item5</li>
                <li>item6</li>
                <li>item7</li>
                <li>item8</li>
            </ul>
            <ul class="hidden xl:flex xl:gap-x-9 text-slate-500">
                <li>item1</li>
                <li>item2</li>
                <li>item4</li>
                <li>item5</li>
                <li>item6</li>
                <li>item7</li>
                <li>item8</li>
        </header>
        <div @click="closeToggle" x-show="open" class="absolute inset-0 z-20 w-full h-screen xl:hidden bg-black/50">
            <!-- This is for overlay -->
        </div>
    </div>
```

I want to overlay or that black effect doesn't apply on the header section. I have tried changing z-index,
moving overlay division out of header tag etc.

Comment: use position fixed to get out of the boundaries. Else move the overlay outside bg-white wrapper. Your header should not be wrapped either if possible.

Comment: that some how worked but the overlay is always being shown even when side menu is close, and by clicking side on overlay side menu won't close